# I am learning gradle kotlin DSL. Why is this code example failing to compile with Gradle 6.7.1?

Tags: kotlin, gradle

the following lines do not compile in my build.gradle.kts, but I do not understand why:

```
tasks.getting(JavaExec::class) {
  standardInput=System.in
}
```

---

```
* What went wrong:
Script compilation error:

Line 21:     standardInput = System.in
                                    ^ Expecting an element
```

What is the correct way to write this?

Comment: [Escaping for Java identifiers that are keywords in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#escaping-for-java-identifiers-that-are-keywords-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kotlin, `in` is a [hard keyword](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html#hard-keywords), which cannot be used as an identifier. To access or declare members named `in`, you have to [surround it with backticks](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#escaping-for-java-identifiers-that-are-keywords-in-kotlin) (`` ` ``):

```kotlin
standardInput = System.`in`
```